# How disable ask me about Run /bin/sh in ansi-term?

Tags: ansi-term

Emacs 27.1

When I run ansi-term, it every time ask me about

```
Run programm /bin/sh
```

I every time answer - yes

Is is possible to disable this question and immediately run **ansi-term**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own command that specifies which program to run, and `ansi-term` won't prompt you:

```
(defun my-ansi-term ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/bin/bash"))
```